How to optimize reading from an ini file by ini4j?
I use Java (Anylogic) and the ini4j library to read the initial parameters of the model from ini file. Right now my code for reading one parameter looks like this:
Wini ini = new Wini(new File(FILE_SETTINGS_NAME)); 
… 
Ini.Section sec = ini.get(“AAA”); 
… 
if (sec.containsKey("useAutoAlgoritm")) { 
useAutoAlgoritm = ini.get(“AAA”, "useAutoAlgoritm", int.class) == 1 ? true : false; 
} 

I don't like the second part of code.
Firstly, I have to use the same name useAutoAlgoritm three times, first to check the existence of the field in the ini file (if it does not exist, then I take the default value). And then twice during assignment.
Secondly, I still haven't figured out how to store a Boolean value in an ini file, so I have to convert one to Boolean
Thirdly, I have a variety of classes, and the composition of variables in them. As a result, it is necessary to essentially write the code again for each class (for each composition of the necessary ones). Maybe there are some universal approaches to downloading?
Thanks
I read this forum examples, and ini4j help

Just perusing the javadoc:
Wini ini = new Wini(new File(FILE_SETTINGS_NAME)); 
… 
Ini.Section sec = ini.get(“AAA”); 
… 
boolean useAutoAlgorithm = sec.get("useAutoAlgoritm", int.class, 0) == 1;
} 

Note:

The API of ini4j is pretty bad, with a ton of methods called get across multiple layers of hierarchies that do wildly different things. At some point "I find that my code is ugly when I use this crappy library" can only be answered by: "Then write your own / suck it up / use another one / write a wrapper with API you do like".
x ? true : false is a very silly thing to write. Just write x.
Whenever you feel you are repeating code, write methods. Your third question is too vague to answer in a more meaningful way.


I think that it is technical mistake

@aled I copy pasted the original and cleaned it up; the false; was a leftover from that. I have edited the answer and corrected the error.
